# Get value in activity from getView of BaseAdapter

Tags: android, listview, baseadapter, getview

I have a `listview` and for that i am using a `BaseAdapter`. I want the value of listitem  in that `Activity` . Below is my code

MainActivity.java

```
ArrayList<String> dkulist = new ArrayList<>();
CustomAdapter adapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main_layout);
    userList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.userList);
    userList.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

CustomAdapter.java

```
public class CustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView,final ViewGroup  parent) {
        if (convertView == null) {
          LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());
          convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listitem, parent, false);
    }        

    TextView Name = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.name);

    Name.setText("Dummy name");
    final boolean click_flag = false;
    convertView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
          if(click_flag) {
             view.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE); // this is also not working
             // How to get this name value in my MainActivity.java
          } else {
             view.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
          }
        }
}
```

Thank in Adv

Comment: click_flag is always going to be false... Where are you changing the flag?

Answer (score 2):

Use an `Interface` to pass the value to `Activity`

```
public interface OnItemClickListener {
    void onItemClick (Object value);
}
```

Implement the above listener in the `Activity` and pass an instance of this to the adapter

```
private final OnItemClickListener mListener;

convertView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
         view.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE); // this will work now
         // This is how to get this name value in my MainActivity.java
         mListener.onItemClick(value);
    }
```

Comment: Please explain i did not understand

Comment: So you can use an interface to communicate between activity and adapter. Writing the complete code below

Answer (score 0):

You need to initialize instance for the Adapter and set to the userlist instead of just passing the unassigned adapter variable.

Answer (score 0):

Activity code:

```
public class MainActivity implements CustomAdapter. OnItemClickListener

ArrayList<String> dkulist = new ArrayList<>();
CustomAdapter adapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main_layout);
    userList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.userList);
    userList.setAdapter(adapter);
}

@override
public void onItemClick (Object value){
// do your stuff here
}
}
```

Adapter code:

```
public class CustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

private final OnItemClickListener mListener;

   public CustomAdapter(Context context){
    // this will register the listener with MainActivity.java
    mListener = (OnItemClickListener) context
   }
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView,final ViewGroup  parent) {
        if (convertView == null) {
          LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());
          convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listitem, parent, false);
    }        

    TextView Name = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.name);

    Name.setText("Dummy name");
    final boolean click_flag = false;
    convertView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
          if(click_flag) {
             view.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE); // this is also not working
             // How to get this name value in my MainActivity.java
             // Add below code to delegate the value to activity
             mListener.onItemClick(value);
          } else {
             view.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
          }
        }

public interface OnItemClickListener {
    void onItemClick (Object value);
}
}
```

Comment: OnItemClickListener is AdapterView.OnItemClickListener ?

Comment: java.lang.ClassCastException in this line mListener = (AdapterView.OnItemClickListener) context;

Answer (score 0):

**Try this**

> In your MainAcitivity.java,

```
userList.setOnItemClickListener(new ListItemClickListener());

private class ListItemClickListenerimplements ListView.OnItemClickListener {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
                                long id) {
            String text = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.name)).getText().toString();
        }

    }
```